# Connecting a switch with power to a plug and a light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to connect a switch, which is receiving power in its box, to a light fixture that is a little far, but also a plug near that light (the plug always powered). I'm almost certain it wouldn't be correct to use a three-wire with two hot wires, right? Do I really need to pass two wires all the way?

Comment: I presume you are asking about a setup where power comes to the switch box, then there is one cable from the switches to the first load and another cable between the two loads? There are other ways to arrange this which would produce slightly different answers.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't indicate what amp circuit this is on, so answering by default, use 12/3 wire. If the controlling breaker is 15 amp you can use 14/3

Neutral (white) and ground to both the light and outlet.

Black to the outlet

Red from the switch to the light.

Comment: For additional clarity: Run the /3 cable from the switch to the light then the additional outlet. Connect the red wire in the /3 to the switch (making it switched hot) and the black to the incoming black wires (making it always hot). At the light connect the red to the bulb base and put a wire nut on the red _leading out of the box_. Run the full /3 cable to the outlet, connecting the black always hot to it (and another wire nut on the red wire).